# How to use TcpClient in Windows 8 Consumer Preview

Tags: windows, windows-8, .net-4.5

I'm writing a Metro app in Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

However, I'm unable to use the TcpClient in .NET 4.5, there doesn't seem to be a place to add the assembly reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1612451t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TcpClient is not supported on the metro side. You can use [StreamSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx) class instead. [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931) is a sample on how to use it to create a TCP Socket, make a connection, send and receive data. The samples are in JS and C++ but the same class will work for C#.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, we should probably use the new Metro NET stuff. However, if porting a lot of code and depending on how much of the TcpClient members you are using, it might not be so bad to just create a limited implementation around the Metro objects. I wanted to do a quick port of a bunch of code over to Metro in a hurry (just to try out some stuff), so I slapped together something that seemed to work, but most certainly not ideal. (You end up doing some sync-ing of async methods which is commonly frowned upon.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace MetroNetHelper
{
public class IPAddress  // assumes IPv4 currently
{
    public string IP_String;
    public IPAddress() { }
    public IPAddress(string IP) { IP_String = IP; }
    public static IPAddress Broadcast { get { return new IPAddress("255.255.255.255"); } }
    public static IPAddress Parse(string IP) { return new IPAddress(IP); }
    public static bool TryParse(string V, out IPAddress Addr)
    {
        try
        {
            Addr = IPAddress.Parse(V);
            return true;
        }
        catch { Addr = null; return false; }
    }
    public HostName GetHostNameObject() { return new HostName(IP_String); }
    public byte[] GetAddressBytes()
    {
        string[] Fields = IP_String.Split('.');
        byte[] temp = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++) temp[i] = byte.Parse(Fields[i]);
        return temp;
    }
}

public class IPEndPoint
{
    public IPAddress Address;
    public int Port;
    public IPEndPoint() { }
    public IPEndPoint(IPAddress Addr, int PortNum)
    {
        Address = Addr; Port = PortNum;
    }
}

public class NetworkStream
{
    private DataReader Reader;
    private DataWriter Writer;

    public void Set(StreamSocket HostClient)
    {
        Reader = new DataReader(HostClient.InputStream);
        Reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        Writer = new DataWriter(HostClient.OutputStream);
    }

    public int Write(byte[] Buffer, int Offset, int Len)
    {
        if (Offset != 0 || Len != Buffer.Length) throw new ArgumentException("Can only write whole byte array");
        Writer.WriteBytes(Buffer);
        Task Tk = Writer.StoreAsync().AsTask();
        Tk.Wait();
        return Buffer.Length;
    }

    public int Read(byte[] Buffer, int Offset, int Len)
    {
        if (Offset != 0 || Len != Buffer.Length) throw new ArgumentException("Can only read whole byte array");
        Task<uint> Tk = Reader.LoadAsync((uint)Len).AsTask<uint>();
        Tk.Wait();
        uint Count = Tk.Result;
        for (int i=0;i<Count;i++)
        {
            Buffer[i] = Reader.ReadByte();
        }
        return (int)Count;
    }

    public bool DataAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            return true; // Read() will still work if no data; could we do read ahead 1 byte to determine?
        }
    }
}


public class TcpClient
{
    private StreamSocket sock;

    public void Connect(IPEndPoint EndPt)
    {
        try
        {
            sock = new StreamSocket();
            HostName Hst = EndPt.Address.GetHostNameObject();
            Task Tsk = sock.ConnectAsync(Hst, EndPt.Port.ToString()).AsTask();
            Tsk.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MetroHelpers.UnpeelAggregate(ex); }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        sock.Dispose();
        sock = null;
    }

    public NetworkStream GetStream()
    {
        var N = new NetworkStream();
        N.Set(sock);
        return N;
    }
}

public static class MetroHelpers
{
    public static void UnpeelAggregate(Exception Ex)
    {
        AggregateException Ag_Ex = Ex as AggregateException;
        if (Ag_Ex == null) throw Ex;
        if (Ag_Ex.InnerExceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            if (Ag_Ex.InnerExceptions.Count == 1) throw Ag_Ex.InnerExceptions[0];
            StringBuilder Str = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Exception X in Ag_Ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Str.AppendLine(X.Message);
            }
            throw new Exception(Str.ToString(), Ag_Ex);
        }
        else throw Ag_Ex;
    }
}
} // END NAMESPACE
```

This was just something I did quick and dirty in a morning. If it helps anyone with ideas, great. Again, we are most likely better off developing the way Microsoft wants us for Metro apps. It just gets frustrating when they keep changing the ruddy framework. (If Xamarin can keep consistent frameworks on iOS/Android/etc, why can't MS on their own OS's!)